# How to add an avatar to gmail messages and contact list

Tags: gmail, avatar, gmail-api

I am not sure if this is possible via Gmail's API (or another method)

What I am looking for specifically is a simple way to add avatars to subject lines or contact list in my gmail account.

Also how to suggest possible workflows to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Contacts API to set profile photos for your contacts. See here for more information:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#addingupdating_a_photo_for_a_contact